# Name "roles" is not defined in autorole event

Tags: python, bots, roles, discord.py

This bot is for leveling and roles. I'm trying to figure out why my auto role code isn't working.

```
import random
import asyncio
import aiohttp
import json
import os
import discord
import codecs
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import Game
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord.utils import get

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    role = discord.utils.get(member.server.roles, name="Village")
    await client.add_roles(member, roles)
```

Error:

```
    Ignoring exception in on_member_join
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\pixel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 307, in _run_event
    yield from getattr(self, event)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\pixel\Downloads\MineBot\wizard.py", line 337, in on_member_join
    await client.add_roles(member, roles)
NameError: name 'roles' is not defined
```

The rest of my code works fine because it sends messages on command which is pretty straight forward.

Comment: It doesn't work for exactly the reason the error says: `name 'roles' is not defined`. Did you mean `role`, or should `roles` be defined outside that function somewhere?

Comment: so I changed `roles` to `role` and got this error
`Ignoring exception in on_member_join
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\pixel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 307, in _run_event
    yield from getattr(self, event)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\pixel\Downloads\MineBot\wizard.py", line 336, in on_member_join
    role = discord.utils.get(member.server.role, name="Village")
AttributeError: 'Server' object has no attribute 'role'`

The tutorial i followed didnt define `roles`. It worked for them :(

Comment: i dont know what i did, but it works now LMAO. Thanks for the help anyway man! now i can finally see the sunlight lol